Existence check on a secret through AWS CDK
Since secrets cannot be easily deleted, is there a way to execute an existence check on it when deploying using CDK?

What exactly do you want to achieve? CloudFormation already does a check and will not proceed if it already exists.

You can use fromSecretNameV2 to import a secret by secret name and verify the existence of the Secret.
Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#methods

This does not verify the existence of the secret.

Were you able to verify that? The fromSecretNameV2 method would return undefined if the secret does not exist.

No, it always returns an ISecret. It does not perform any API calls - it simply creates a read-only reference to some ARN.

Using the ISecret object, you can perform checks on properties like secretArn that should trigger the API call. That should help with the existence check.
But as @gshpychka mentioned, Cloudformation already performs these checks and will not proceed if the secret does not exist.

No, that's not how it works. Accessing properties never triggers an API call. Doing this will not check for the secret's existence at all.
P.S. I am @gshpychka :)
